# Replace Strings with specific list of words

Tags: java, string, replace

Replace a given string at given index with list of words.
The problem statement goes below, can someone give me some intuition or idea how to proceed on this?

```
//A replacement class similar to Linked List
class Replacement {
        int start;
        String before;
        String after;

    //Method to replace the words
    public static String replaceRanges(String text, List<Replacement> replacements) {
        //TODO your code here
        return null;
    }

}

/* below is the example of the problem
    Example #1:
    Input: 
    text = "num foo"
    replacements = [
    {start: 0, before: "num", after: "String"},
    {start: 4, before: "foo", after: "bar"}
    ]
    Output:
    replaceRanges(text, replacements) returns:
    "String bar"
    Example #2: Input: text = "num_fooBar", Output: "String_barBar"
*/
```

Comment: String has a replace()  and a replaceAll() function. If this is a school assignment, good luck.  If not, look up the String API methods.

Comment: Also `String` is one of the implementations of `CharSequence` interface.

Comment: Okay, but how to make use of the Replacement class here? that is a List<Replacement> not String

Comment: @Nilanjan you can iterate through it `for (Replacement r : replacements)` and then access the properties `r.before` and `r.after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your replacements sorted from smallest index to highest, you can iterate the list from last to first and search for substrings in input string and replace them if they match

```
public static String replaceRanges(String text, List<Replacement> replacements) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(text);

    for (int i = replacements.size() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        Replacement r = replacements.get(i);
        int begin = r.start;
        int end = r.start + r.before.length();
        if (begin >= 0 && begin < s.length() && end >= 0 && end <= s.length()) {
            if (s.substring(begin, end).equals(r.before)) {
                s.replace(begin, end, r.after);
            }
        }
    }

    return s.toString();
}
```

If your list is not sorted, you need to sort it first using `Collections.sort()`.

I used this code for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Replacement> replacements = List.of(
            new Replacement(0, "num", "String"), 
            new Replacement(4, "foo", "bar"));

    System.out.println(replaceRanges("num foo", replacements)); // Output: String bar
    System.out.println(replaceRanges("num_fooBar", replacements)); // Output: String_barBar
    System.out.println(replaceRanges("num_f", replacements)); // Output: String_f
    System.out.println(replaceRanges("", replacements)); // Output: 
    System.out.println(replaceRanges("foonum", replacements)); // Output: foonum
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your code, but it shows error for the input mentioned in above code-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start 7, end 10, length 7
 at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.checkRangeSIOOBE(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1724)
 at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1017)
 at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:85)
 at Algo.StringReplacement.replaceRanges2(StringReplacement.java:29)
 at Algo.StringReplacement.main(StringReplacement.java:67)

Comment: Post here what tests are not working, I tried it with two tests you provided above and it worked for them. But you are right that I wasn't checking if indexes are withing bounds. I edited the code and also included my testing code. Try to run it and if it doesn't work, write here your tests. Also my  code is still not null safe, if you expect nulls in your input, you need to add null checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your original string one by one and keep in mind that you have to shift the `start` position (because you could replace the small substring to the bigger substring)

```
public String replaceRanges(String text, List<Replacement> replacements) {
    for(int i = 0; i < replacements.size(); i++) {
        Replacement replacement = replacements.get(i);
        String firstPart = text.substring(0, replacement.start);
        String secondPart = text.substring(replacement.start, text.length());
        String updatedSecondPart = secondPart.replace(replacement.before, replacement.after);
        text = firstPart + updatedSecondPart;
        updateStart(i + 1, replacements, updatedSecondPart.length() - secondPart.length());
    }
    return text;
}

privat void updateStart(int startIndex, List<Replacement> replacements, int shift) {
    for( int i = startIndex; i < replacements.size(); i++) {
        Replacement r = replacements.get(i);
        r.start += shift;
    }
}
```

Using this method you can process:

```
Replacement r1 = new Replacement(0, "hi", "Hello");
Replacement r2 = new Replacement(2, "lo", "p");
Sting result = replaceRanges("hi louie!", asList(r1, r2)); //result = 'Hello puie!'
```

Comment: Thanks you for your code, that works. I will try to improve the Time Complexity.